# laravel file system returns string of data instead of video

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to get a video from laravel file system like below :

```
   $fileData  = FileStorage::where('path', $name)->first();
        $directory = $this->getDirectoryPathById($fileData->directory_id, false);
        $path      = Storage::disk('sftp')->get('/home/files/public/' . $directory . '/' . $fileData->path);
        return $path;
```

but the path is not the .mp4 video that i except its a long string with unknown chars like imagebelow :
[image]

Comment: You could use responses like download,  or streamDownload https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads

Comment: no because i am getting the file from other server and i cant give the path to it

Comment: What you got if you do `return response()->download($path);` or `return response()->file($path);`?